# matrix of $T^*$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that $V=M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with inner product $<A,B>=trace(B^*A)$, 
we define $T:V\to V$ by $T(A)=MA, M\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, could any one help me to find the expression of $T^*(A)$?

I thought like this $<A,T(A)>=<T^*(A),A>$
$\Rightarrow <A,MA>=<T^*(A),A>$
 but after that I am unable to proceed. help

Comment: You have used the definition of $T^{*}$, good, So what have you not yet exploited?

Comment: Besides, it should be $\langle B,T(A)\rangle=\langle T^*(B),A\rangle$ in the definition.

Comment: @A.G. technically, either is fine over $\Bbb C$

Comment: The title seems to have nothing to do with the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$
\langle A,T(B) \rangle = 
\langle A,M B \rangle = tr((MB)^*A) = tr(B^*M^*A) = \\
tr(B^*(M^*A)) = \langle M^*A,B \rangle = \langle T^*(A),B \rangle
$$